# add a li in between instead of append or prepend

Tags: html, dom

I want to add a new li to a list an already existing UL..

**thing is I want to add it a to a pre-defined index.**

.append() and .prepend() are adding to li to the last and first .

**let say I want to add li after the second child(li)** (snake)..

```js
 
function myFunction() {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("water");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Crow</li>
  <li>snake</li>
  <li>Lion</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Help Me add water after snake</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Can you use `jquery` for this??

Comment: yeah... i couldnt find a jquery answer as well... show me if you got it

Comment: I am re-editing my question  .. for this ul I want item1 to be at top https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaaaML

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
  function myFunction(position) {
    var allElems = document.querySelectorAll('#myList li');
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("water");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.querySelector('#myList').insertBefore(node, allElems[position - 1])
  }


<ul id="myList">
  <li>Crow</li>
  <li>snake</li>
  <li>Lion</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Help Me add water after snake</p>

<button onclick="myFunction(3)">Try it</button>
```

It takes a parameter of which position you would like your new value.

https://jsfiddle.net/mcjzhr35/

Comment: It's kinda pointless setting it in the button IMO as that would have to be hard coded. You might as well just put it in the function.

Comment: True, for this question. But what if Raja wants another button for adding another element to another position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method with the [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to achieve this in `jquery`:

```
$("ul li:eq(1)").after($("<li>Water</li>"));
```

Note that, since `:eq()` is zero-based, so the index will start from 0

```js
function myFunction() {
    $("ul li:eq(1)").after($("<li>Water</li>"));

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Crow</li>
  <li>snake</li>
  <li>Lion</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Help Me add water after snake</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: I want item i to be at top

Answer (score 1):

For a non jQuery way, you can use `.querySelectorAll("li")[1]` and then select the index.

Remember, `0` = the first element (Crow), `1` = Snake, `2` = Lion etc..

```js
function myFunction() {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("water");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("myList").querySelectorAll("li")[1].appendChild(node);
}
```

```html
<ul id="myList">
  <li>Crow</li>
  <li>snake</li>
  <li>Lion</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
</ul>

<p>Help Me add water after snake</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) together with the [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) selector.

```
function myFunction() {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("water");
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    //document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
    var priorNode = document.querySelector("#myList li:nth-child(3)");
    document.getElementById("myList").insertBefore(node, priorNode);
}
```

`querySelector` is used to get the third li and `insertBefore` adds the water node before this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the pure JS approach try insertBefore, you just need parentNode and node you want to insert before.

```
              function myFunction() {
                 var node = document.createElement("LI");
                 var textnode = document.createTextNode("water");
                 node.appendChild(textnode);

                var myList = window.document.getElementById("myList");
                var lion = window.document.getElementById("lion");
                //assume lion has an id
                myList.insertBefore(node, lion);
               }
```